# Delete files in subfolder using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have to delete files from a sub folder with a same name. My file path is like as follows.

```
d:\test\test1\archive\*.txt
d:\test\try\archive\*.txt
d:\test\model\archive\*.txt
```

I tried deleting using `del` command in batch script. 
But there are more than 100 folders with in the folder "*test*". So it is very difficult to use `del` for each and every path.

Except for the parent folder name of "archive" folder, everything remains the same for all the paths. So I guess there might be some easy way to delete the files using batch script.

Can anyone guide me whether there is any easy way to delete the files using batch script? Or i have to repeat `del` for all 100 folders?

Answer (score 33):

You can use the `/s` switch for `del` to delete in subfolders as well.

Example

```
del D:\test\*.* /s
```

Would delete all files under test including all files in all subfolders.

To remove folders use `rd`, same switch applies.

```
rd D:\test\folder /s /q
```

`rd` doesn't support wildcards `*` though so if you want to recursively delete all subfolders under the `test` directory you can use a `for` loop.

```
for /r /d D:\test %a in (*) do rd %a /s /q
```

If you are using the `for` option in a batch file remember to use 2 `%`'s instead of 1.

Answer (score 5):

Use powershell inside your bat file

```
PowerShell Remove-Item c:\scripts\* -include *.txt -exclude *test* -force -recurse
```

You can also exclude from removing some specific folder or file:

```
PowerShell Remove-Item C:/*  -Exclude WINDOWS,autoexec.bat -force -recurse
```

Answer (score 4):

*Moved from the closed topic*

```
del /s d:\test\archive*.txt
```

This should get you all of your text files

Alternatively,

I modified a script I already wrote to look for certain files to move them, this one should go and find files and delete them. It allows you to just choose to which folder by a selection screen.

Please test this on your system before using it though.

```
@echo off
Title DeleteFilesInSubfolderList
color 0A
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

REM ---------------------------
REM   *** EDIT VARIABLES BELOW ***
REM ---------------------------

set targetFolder=
REM targetFolder is the location you want to delete from    
REM ---------------------------
REM  *** DO NOT EDIT BELOW ***
REM ---------------------------

IF NOT DEFINED targetFolder echo.Please type in the full BASE Symform Offline Folder (I.E. U:\targetFolder)
IF NOT DEFINED targetFolder set /p targetFolder=:
cls
echo.Listing folders for: %targetFolder%\^*
echo.-------------------------------
set Index=1
for /d %%D in (%targetFolder%\*) do (
  set "Subfolders[!Index!]=%%D"
  set /a Index+=1
)
set /a UBound=Index-1
for /l %%i in (1,1,%UBound%) do echo. %%i. !Subfolders[%%i]!

:choiceloop
echo.-------------------------------
set /p Choice=Search for ERRORS in: 
if "%Choice%"=="" goto chioceloop
if %Choice% LSS 1 goto choiceloop
if %Choice% GTR %UBound% goto choiceloop
set Subfolder=!Subfolders[%Choice%]!
goto start

:start
TITLE Delete Text Files - %Subfolder%
IF NOT EXIST %ERRPATH% goto notExist
IF EXIST %ERRPATH% echo.%ERRPATH% Exists - Beginning to test-delete files...
echo.Searching for .txt files...
pushd %ERRPATH%
for /r %%a in (*.txt) do (
echo "%%a" "%Subfolder%\%%~nxa"
)
popd
echo.
echo.
verIFy >nul
echo.Execute^?
choice /C:YNX /N /M "(Y)Yes or (N)No:"
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='1' set question1=Y
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='2' set question1=N
IF /I '%question1%'=='Y' goto execute
IF /I '%question1%'=='N' goto end

:execute
echo.%ERRPATH% Exists - Beginning to delete files...
echo.Searching for .txt files...
pushd %ERRPATH%
for /r %%a in (*.txt) do (
del "%%a" "%Subfolder%\%%~nxa"
)
popd
goto end

:end
echo.
echo.
echo.Finished deleting files from %subfolder%
pause
goto choiceloop
ENDLOCAL
exit


REM Created by Trevor Giannetti
REM An unpublished work
REM (October 2012)
```

If you change the

```
set targetFolder=
```

to the folder you want you won't get prompted for the folder.
*Remember when putting the base path in, the format does not include a '\' on the end.
e.g. 
d:\test
c:\temp

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

I had to complete the same task and I used a "for" loop and a "del" command as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF

set dir=%cd%

FOR /d /r %dir% %%x in (archive\) do (
    if exist "%%x" del %%x\*.txt /f /q
)
```

You can set the dir variable with any start directory you want or used the current directory (%cd%) variable.

These are the options for "for" command:

- /d  For directories
- /r  For recursive

These are the options for "del" command:

- /f  Force deletes read-only files
- /q  Quiet mode; suppresses prompts for delete confirmations.

Answer (score 0):

`del parentpath` (or just place the .bat file inside parent folder) *.txt /s

That will delete all .txt files in the parent and all sub folders. If you want to delete multiple file extensions just add a space and do the same thing.  Ex.  *.txt *.dll *.xml