# Delete .txt files in subfolders using batch script

Tags: batch-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delete files in subfolder using batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800575/delete-files-in-subfolder-using-batch-script)

I have to delete .txt files from a sub folder (with same name). My filepath is like as follows.

d:\test\test1\archive*.txt
d:\test\try\archive*.txt
d:\test\model\archive*.txt

I tried "del" command to delete the ".txt" files in above paths. But there are more than 100 folders in the folder "test". So it is very difficult to use "del" for each and every path.

Except the parent folder name of "archive" folder, everything remains the same for all the paths. So I guess there might be some easy way to delete the files using batch script.

Can anyone guide me whether there is any easy way to delete .txt files using batch script Or I have to repeat "del" for all 100 folders?

Comment: You just asked this an hour ago - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800575/delete-files-in-subfolder-using-batch-script/13800688#13800688 which I have already answered, why are you asking the same question again?

Answer (score 4):

```
del /s *.txt
```

hope it helps.All the best mate

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There exists .txt files in test1/try/model folders also. But I have to delete .txt files that exists only in archive subfolder of folders test1/try/model. Can you help on this?

Answer (score 2):

`del /s *.txt` will delete all TXT files in all subfolders of current working directory.

(But use that command carefully - wrong parent directory and you are throwing away all textfiles on your computer :) )

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There exists .txt files in test1/try/model folders also. But I have to delete .txt files that exists only in archive subfolder of folders test1/try/model. Can you help on this?

Comment: @Satheesh start the script from your model folder and use `del /s archive\*.txt`

Answer (score 0):

*Edited*

```
del /s d:\test\archive\*.txt
```

This should get you all of your text files

Alternatively,

I modified a script I already wrote to look for certain files to move them, this one should go and find files and delete them. It allows you to just choose to which folder by a selection screen.

Please test this on your system before using it though.

```
@echo off
Title DeleteFilesInSubfolderList
color 0A
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

REM ---------------------------
REM   *** EDIT VARIABLES BELOW ***
REM ---------------------------

set targetFolder=
REM targetFolder is the location you want to delete from    
REM ---------------------------
REM  *** DO NOT EDIT BELOW ***
REM ---------------------------

IF NOT DEFINED targetFolder echo.Please type in the full BASE Symform Offline Folder (I.E. U:\targetFolder)
IF NOT DEFINED targetFolder set /p targetFolder=:
cls
echo.Listing folders for: %targetFolder%\^*
echo.-------------------------------
set Index=1
for /d %%D in (%targetFolder%\*) do (
  set "Subfolders[!Index!]=%%D"
  set /a Index+=1
)
set /a UBound=Index-1
for /l %%i in (1,1,%UBound%) do echo. %%i. !Subfolders[%%i]!

:choiceloop
echo.-------------------------------
set /p Choice=Search for ERRORS in: 
if "%Choice%"=="" goto chioceloop
if %Choice% LSS 1 goto choiceloop
if %Choice% GTR %UBound% goto choiceloop
set Subfolder=!Subfolders[%Choice%]!
goto start

:start
TITLE Delete Text Files - %Subfolder%
IF NOT EXIST %ERRPATH% goto notExist
IF EXIST %ERRPATH% echo.%ERRPATH% Exists - Beginning to test-delete files...
echo.Searching for .txt files...
pushd %ERRPATH%
for /r %%a in (*.txt) do (
echo "%%a" "%Subfolder%\%%~nxa"
)
popd
echo.
echo.
verIFy >nul
echo.Execute^?
choice /C:YNX /N /M "(Y)Yes or (N)No:"
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='1' set question1=Y
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='2' set question1=N
IF /I '%question1%'=='Y' goto execute
IF /I '%question1%'=='N' goto end

:execute
echo.%ERRPATH% Exists - Beginning to delete files...
echo.Searching for .txt files...
pushd %ERRPATH%
for /r %%a in (*.txt) do (
del "%%a" "%Subfolder%\%%~nxa"
)
popd
goto end

:end
echo.
echo.
echo.Finished deleting files from %subfolder%
pause
goto choiceloop
ENDLOCAL
exit


REM Created by Trevor Giannetti
REM An unpublished work
REM (October 2012)
```

If you change the

```
set targetFolder=
```

to the folder you want you won't get prompted for the folder.
*Remember when putting the base path in, the format does not include a '\' on the end.
e.g. 
d:\test
c:\temp

Hope this helps